# How to refresh a JPanel after user inputs something?

Tags: java, swing

Say a game allows you to choose a number of players, and then asks for each player's name based on that number.
The first user inputs their name in a JTextField, and clicks a JButton (which stores their name in a list).

After the button is clicked, the JPanel erases the user's name from the JTextField so that the second person may enter their name, and so on.

How would I do this? Would I use a loop?

Comment: No, you can't use a loop directly, you need to use a pseudo loop, which each time the `JButton` is actioned, you update a variable which indicates which iteration of the loop you're know in.  A better solution might be to add `n` number of text fields based on the number of players the user initially set

Answer (score 2):

> How would I do this? Would I use a loop?

Nope. Using a loop is a construct that you'd use in a linear console-driven programming environment to get repeated input from the user. Instead Swing is an *event-driven* library, and in this situation you have to think differently since here you'd use *state-dependent* interaction with the user.

So say you wanted to get 5 records of information from the user, you'd use a counter, and each time the submit button is pressed, you'd get the input from the GUI components, create an object with them add them to whatever collection is holding the information, perhaps an ArrayList or a JTable's model, and then when the maximum number is reached by the counter (the state variable that you'd be monitoring), you'd stop getting input, and perhaps even change the GUI view entirely to reflect this change in state, something that you could use a CardLayout to help with.